# how can i determine the ACTUAL return type of a specific subclass of a generic superclass?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, runtime

i do know that what i am trying to do it isn't really possible with pure java - it is only possible if i look at the debug info. i will not compile without debug anyway, because a buch of my spring mvc would stop working.

that said, i have the following situation:

**one generic superclass:**

package com.cinefms.apitester.springmvc.crawlers;

```
public class TestGenerics<T extends TestGenericsInterface> {

    public T get() {
        return null;
    }

    public T put(T t) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**and its subclass:**

```
package com.cinefms.apitester.springmvc.crawlers;


public class TestGenericsSub extends TestGenerics<TestGenericsImpl> {

}
```

with the objects in there being really damn simple.

**an interface:**

```
package com.cinefms.apitester.springmvc.crawlers;

public interface TestGenericsInterface {

}
```

**and it's implementation:**

```
package com.cinefms.apitester.springmvc.crawlers;

public class TestGenericsImpl implements TestGenericsInterface {

}
```

eclipse is perfectly fine figuring out that of `TestGenericsSub.get()` should return an instance of `TestGenericsImpl` ... even if no source is available.

but how can i possible figure this out by myself at runtime?

if "m" is the Method "run", then

```
m.getGenericReturnType();
```

would return "T" (not helpful), while:

```
m.getReturnType();
```

gives me "TestGenericsInterface" (also not helpful). i have been looking at the "org.javaruntype" library ... but i can't seem to be able to figure it out.

could someone explain?

thanks!

Comment: You cannot, in general, determine the ACTUAL return type of a method without inspecting the code in the method (generic or not).  At best you can determine the FORMAL return type specified in the method declaration (with appropriate generic swizzle), but the method can always return a subclass of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with [ClassMate](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-classmate):

```
TypeResolver typeResolver = new TypeResolver();
MemberResolver memberResolver = new MemberResolver(typeResolver);

ResolvedType resolvedType = typeResolver.resolve(TestGenericsSub.class);
ResolvedTypeWithMembers resolvedTypeWithMembers = memberResolver.resolve(resolvedType, null, null);
ResolvedMethod resolvedGetMethod = resolvedTypeWithMembers.getMemberMethods()[0];

System.out.println(resolvedGetMethod.getReturnType()); // TestGenericsImpl
```

Comment: yes, this is pretty much what i was looking for. i found it quite difficult to do in org.javaruntime - there, i could get all the necessary information, but i would have to resolve superclass generics variables myself - a bit of a pain really. thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Java type erasure (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html), this is quite difficult. I suggest saving the class off as an attribute and then providing a getter if you absolutely must know the run-time type of T.

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> {

    private final Class<T> type;

    public MyGenericClass(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Class<T> getMyType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can try something like:

```
(Class<T extends TestGenericsInterface>) ((TestGenerics) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

I would prefer the former solution to the latter in code.

Comment: hi. the thing is that i am actually doing introspection on other people's code. specifically, i am trying to extract information from spring MVC controllers for this:


 https://github.com/rmalchow/spring-api-tester
 
so i cannot actually control the code. in general, i agree.